# How to format xml instead of original format in springMVC (Restful webservice)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, spring-mvc

Currently, I want to return the return xml result with XML with the below format :

I tried to use something like this

```
       @XmlRootElement(name = "item")

public class Book implements Serializable {

 @XmlAttribute


public int getBookId() {


return bookId;
    }
```

...

....
and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "OneBoxResults")
public class JavaClazz {

private List<Book> OneBoxResults;

public List<Book> getOneBoxResults() {
    return OneBoxResults;
}
@XmlElements(@XmlElement(name = "book", type = Book.class))
public void setOneBoxResults(List<Book> oneBoxResults) {
    OneBoxResults = oneBoxResults;
}
...
```

However, the return result which I received is only Json format as below :

{"oneBoxResults":[{"bookId":1,"bookName":"Search
Deployment","update":"2014-01-07","description":"A successful deployment
typically involves the following
elements:","path":null},{"bookId":2,"bookName":"GSA
Information","update":"2015-01-07","description":"Configure the OneBox
module so it sends search queries to the provider (a custom
application","path":null}]}

I also attemped to create new format in controller as below :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest.oneboxSample",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String oneboxSample(){
    String tmpOpenField = "<Field name=\"";
    String tmpCloseField = "</Field>";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
    builder.append("<OneBoxResults>").append("<resultCode>");
    builder.append("Listbook").append("<resultCode>");
    for(int i = 0; i < bookDao.getBooks().size(); i++){
        Book tmpBook = bookDao.getBooks().get(i);
        builder.append("<MODULE_RESULT>");
        builder.append(tmpOpenField).append("bookId\">").append(tmpBook.getBookId()).append(tmpCloseField);
        builder.append(tmpOpenField).append("bookName\">").append(tmpBook.getBookName()).append(tmpCloseField);
        builder.append(tmpOpenField).append("update\">").append(tmpBook.getUpdate()).append(tmpCloseField);
        builder.append(tmpOpenField).append("description\">").append(tmpBook.getDescription()).append(tmpCloseField);
        builder.append(tmpOpenField).append("path\">").append(tmpBook.getPath()).append(tmpCloseField);
        builder.append("</MODULE_RESULT>");
    }
    builder.append("</OneBoxResults>");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

But the result is not good. It returned a string instead of xml format which we need.

Now, our system need to receive a xml format instead of an original xml format.
Please tell me know the way to do it .

The below is my source code which I wrote

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tyg0kp7gkzodod/onebox-service.zip?dl=0

Thanks,

Comment: We'll need to know about your Spring configuration. In particular, if you're not using Spring Boot, you probably forgot to register an XML message converter.

Comment: I uploaded my source in the above. I appriciate your help in this case. thanks.https://www.dropbox.com/s/4tyg0kp7gkzodod/onebox-service.zip?dl=0